# make background transparent and inactive when sidbar expands

Tags: html, css

I have this below code where i am trying to make the background inactive and transparent when the Open sidebar button is clicked.

Once the sidebar button is clicked the background should become transparent and locked (means user cant click sidebar button anymore)

Currently i am able to make the background transparent , but I am unable to lock it. I can still click the button.

And second thing, background is becoming transparent on page load, how can we make background transparent when the "Open Sidebar" button is clicked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    
    .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #111;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .sidebar a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .outer-modal {
      z-index: 3;
      display: block;
      padding-top: 100px;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    
    .sidebar a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .sidebar .closebtn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    .openbtn {
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #111;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .openbtn:hover {
      background-color: #444;
    }
    
    #main {
      transition: margin-left .5s;
      padding: 16px;
    }
    /* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidebar {
        padding-top: 15px;
      }
      .sidebar a {
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div id="main" class="outer-modal">
    <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Open Sidebar</button>
    <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
    <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    
    .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #111;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .sidebar a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .outer-modal {
      z-index: 3;
      display: block;
      padding-top: 100px;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    
    .sidebar a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .sidebar .closebtn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    .openbtn {
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #111;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .openbtn:hover {
      background-color: #444;
    }
    
    #main {
      transition: margin-left .5s;
      padding: 16px;
    }
    /* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidebar {
        padding-top: 15px;
      }
      .sidebar a {
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
    
    .hidden {
      opacity: 0.5;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div id="main" class="outer-modal">
    <button id='openbtn' class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Open Sidebar</button>
    <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
    <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").classList.add('hidden')
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").classList.remove('hidden')
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @sfdcfox I have made a few changes, you can try again.

Answer (score 0):

I used `filter: opacity(0.5/1)` and `pointer-events: none/all`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    
    .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #111;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
    
    .sidebar a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #818181;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .outer-modal {
      z-index: 3;
      display: block;
      padding-top: 100px;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    
    .sidebar a:hover {
      color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .sidebar .closebtn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    .openbtn {
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #111;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      border: none;
    }
    
    .openbtn:hover {
      background-color: #444;
    }
    
    #main {
      transition: margin-left .5s;
      padding: 16px;
    }
    /* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidebar {
        padding-top: 15px;
      }
      .sidebar a {
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div id="main" class="outer-modal">
    <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Open Sidebar</button>
    <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
    <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.pointerEvents = "none";
      document.getElementById("main").style.filter = "opacity(0.5)";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.pointerEvents = "all";
      document.getElementById("main").style.filter = "opacity(1)";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```